# How to print the sum of a column from a CSV file without using pandas?

Tags: python, csv, sorting, sum, etl

I do have a CSV file for example called PC_Sales.csv with sorted values according to Country and Year.

```
Country           Year           Manufacturer     Sales_Unit
India             2017                Intel          50  
India             2017                 HP            60
India             2018                Intel          10
USA               2017                Lenevo         20
USA               2017                 HP            30
USA               2017                Lenevo         40
USA               2018                Intel          30
USA               2018                 HP            30
```

I have sorted out the data according as per Country and Year Column. So I have to prompt user to ask for a number between 1 and 2. If the user enters 1, it will show the sum of the total Sales_Units of India and USA with the Header. For example,
The output will be something like this if the user enters 1:

```
Country     Sales_Units
India           120
USA             150
```

And when the user will enter 2 it will show output like this (sum of the Sales_Units of each country's manufacturer):

```
Country               Manufacturer            Sales_Units
India                    Intel                    60
                           HP                     60

USA                      Lenevo                   60
                          HP                      60
                         Intel                    30
```

Comment: please try use csv library to read the file into python data structure.

Comment: (1) Why do you now want to use pandas? (2) Have you written some code already? Where are you stuck precisely? How did you manage to sort the data? Was it using python? What does the data currently look like in your python program?

Comment: Yes the sorting was done using python. I am not trying to use PANDA! I am trying to print out the values WITHOUT using PANDA! It’s more like data warehouse where I need to print the total Unit_Sales of Particular Countries and Manufacturer based on the input provided by the user! The data looks exactly same as the first table that I mentioned above after sorting! I sorted the data using the lambda function in python!